# Creating index and adding mapping in Elasticsearch with java api gives missing analyzer errors

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch

Code is in Scala. It is extremely similar to Java code.

Code that our map indexer uses to create index: https://gist.github.com/a16e5946b67c6d12b2b8

Utilities that the above code uses to create index and mapping: https://gist.github.com/4f88033204cd761abec0

Errors that java gives: https://gist.github.com/d6c835233e2b606a7074

Response of http://elasticsearch.domain/maps/_settings after running code and getting errors: https://gist.github.com/06ca7112ce1b01de3944

JSON FILES: 
https://gist.github.com/bbab15d699137f04ad87
https://gist.github.com/73222e300be9fffd6380

Attached are the json files i'm loading in. I have confirmed that it is loading the right json files and properly outputting it as a string into .loadFromSource and .setSource.

Any ideas why it can't find the analyzers even though they are in _settings? If I run these json files via curl they work fine and properly setup the mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code I was using to create the index (found here: [Define custom ElasticSearch Analyzer using Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275727/define-custom-elasticsearch-analyzer-using-java-api)) was creating settings in the index like:

"index.settings.analysis.filter.my_snow.type: "stemmer","

It had settings in the setting path.

I changed my indexing code to the following to fix this:

```
def createIndex(client: Client, indexName: String, indexFile: String) {
  //Create index
    client.admin().indices().prepareCreate(indexName)
    .setSource(Utils.loadFileAsString(indexFile))
    .execute()
    .actionGet()
}
```