# How can we define filters/properties for a elasticsearch index using Spark with Scala?

Tags: python, scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark

I used following function in Python to initialize an index in Elasticsearch.

```
def init_index():
    constants.ES_CLIENT.indices.create(
        index = constants.INDEX_NAME,
        body = {
                "settings": {
                    "index": {
                        "type": "default"
                    },
                    "number_of_shards": 1,
                    "number_of_replicas": 1,
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "ap_stop": {
                            "type": "stop",
                            "stopwords_path": "stoplist.txt"
                        },
                        "shingle_filter" : {
                            "type" : "shingle",
                            "min_shingle_size" : 2,
                            "max_shingle_size" : 5,
                            "output_unigrams": True
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        constants.ANALYZER_NAME : {
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard",
                            "filter": ["standard",
                                       "ap_stop",
                                       "lowercase",
                                       "shingle_filter",
                                       "snowball"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )

    new_mapping = {
        constants.TYPE_NAME: {
            "properties": {
                "text": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": True,
                    "index": "analyzed",
                    "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
                    "search_analyzer": constants.ANALYZER_NAME,
                    "index_analyzer": constants.ANALYZER_NAME
                }
            }
        }
    }

    constants.ES_CLIENT.indices.put_mapping (
        index = constants.INDEX_NAME,
        doc_type = constants.TYPE_NAME,
        body = new_mapping
    )
```

Using this function I was able to create an index by user-defined specs.

I recently started to work with scala and spark. For integrating elasticsearch into this I can either use Spark's API i.e. `org.elasticsearch.spark` or I can use Hadoop `org.elasticsearch.hadoop`. Most of the examples I see are related to Hadoop's methodology but I don't wish to use Hadoop here. I went through Spark-elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html#spark) and was able to atleast index documents without including Hadoop but I noticed that this created everything default, I can't even specify `_id` there. It generates `_id` on its own.

In scala I use the following code for indexing (not complete code):

```
val document = mutable.Map[String, String]()
document("id") = docID
document("text") = textChunk.mkString(" ") //textChunk is a list of Strings
sc.makeRDD(Seq(document)).saveToEs("es_park_ap/document")
```

This created an index this way:

```
{
   "es_park_ap": {
      "mappings": {
         "document": {
            "properties": {
               "id": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "text": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "creation_date": "1433006647684",
            "uuid": "QNXcTamgQgKx7RP-h8FVIg",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "version": {
               "created": "1040299"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So if I pass a document to it, a following document is created:

```
     {
        "_index": "es_park_ap",
        "_type": "document",
        "_id": "AU2l2ixcAOrl_Gagnja5",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "text": "some large text",
           "id": "12345"
        }
     }
```

Just like Python, how can I use Spark and Scala to create an index with user defined specifications?

Answer (score 2):

I think we should divide your question to several smaller issues.

If you want to create an index with specific mapping / settings you should use elasticsearch JAVA api directly (You can use it from Scala code of course).
You can use the following sources for examples of index creating using Scala:

[Creating index and adding mapping in Elasticsearch with java api gives missing analyzer errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608196/creating-index-and-adding-mapping-in-elasticsearch-with-java-api-gives-missing-a)

[Define custom ElasticSearch Analyzer using Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275727/define-custom-elasticsearch-analyzer-using-java-api)

Elasticsearch Hadoop / Spark plugin is used in order transport data easily from HDFS to ES. ES maintenance should be done separately.

The fact that you still seeing automatically generated id is because you must specify to the plugin your id field using the following syntax:

```
EsSpark.saveToEs(rdd, "spark/docs", Map("es.mapping.id" -> "your_id_field"))
```

Or in your case:

```
sc.makeRDD(Seq(document)).saveToEs("es_park_ap/document", Map("es.mapping.id" -> "your_id_field"))
```

You can find more details about syntax and proper use here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html

Michael

Comment: Agree. Spark objective is different than maintaining and working with ES cluster. As such Spark works as abstraction on top of ES. You should use any scala client (if you are using scala) listed here for working with ES cluster https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/community/current/clients.html