# how to use wildCardQuery method using elasticsearch Java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I index a document like that:

```
JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject1.put("name_surname", "Cristiano Ronaldo");
    jsonObject1.accumulate("teams", "Sporting Lizbon");
    jsonObject1.accumulate("teams", "Manchester United");
    jsonObject1.accumulate("teams", "Real Madrid");
    jsonObject1.put("2014 rank", 1);

    client.prepareIndex("company", "employee", "1").setSource(jsonObject1.toString()).execute().actionGet();
```

I can search it and get hit with below query:

```
  QueryBuilder qb=QueryBuilders.matchQuery("2014 rank", 1);
  SearchResponse searchResponse=client.prepareSearch().setQuery(qb).execute().actionGet();
```

But wildCardQuery doesn't seem to work:

`QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("name_surname","*naldo");`

I think there is a problem with analyzers when I index it. Is whitespace the problem and if it is how can i fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it and i can use wildCardQuery after i have examined [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275727/define-custom-elasticsearch-analyzer-using-java-api) question.

I use settings below before i index my documents.

```
Node node = nodeBuilder().client(true).settings(ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().loadFromSource(jsonBuilder()
            .startObject()
            .startObject("analysis")
            .startObject("analyzer")
            .startObject("steak")
            .field("type", "custom")
            .field("tokenizer", "standard")
            .field("filter", new String[]{"snowball", "standard", "lowercase"})
            .endObject()
            .endObject()
            .endObject()
            .endObject().string())).clusterName("elasticsearch").node();
```