# ElasticSearch custom analyzer for query using Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Can someone please indicate how a custom analyzer should be defined and then used in an ElasticSearch query using the Java API?

I know how to write a custom analyzer to be applied on an index ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275727/define-custom-elasticsearch-analyzer-using-java-api))

but I would like to apply it on a query e.g. to replace the english analyzer in

`QueryBuilder matchQuery = matchQuery("content", stringQuery).analyzer("english");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom analyzer is a property of particular field in the index. It's always applied on both query and the indexed data. Set custom analyzer with index settings or a template and it will be used for the query.